# Rsync stuck in D state

Tags: rsync, file-copy, aws, file-transfer

I'm moving about 1 TB data from an EBS mounted on my EC2 to another EFS mounted on the same instance. I've been able to copy about 840 GB of data using rsync within the past 2 weeks or so. Now when I've been running rsync to copy the remaining data it keeps showing up as D state in the htop output. This is an email archive server using Mail Piler. 
The rsync command used is as follows:

```
nohup rsync -vaAP --progress /var/piler/store/* /var/efs/store | tee /root/txlog_20June.txt &
```

Can someone shed some light on this and help me out? Is there another method to do it or can I tweak rsync to finish this?

Answer (score 2):

It hard to say extactly what the problem might be, but there are some ideas you can try:

Since the `D` state is uninterruptible sleep, which is caused most likely by I/O operations, I guess that `rsync` is waiting for I/O on a file which is not accessible for some reason. EFS and EBS are both remote filesystems. I had a similar issue with an NFS share. To investigate the problem you can start perform a syscall trace on your `rsync` command. You need `strace` for this (maybe you need to install it first). Then try the following command:

```
strace -eopen -ostrace.log rsync ...
```

- `-eopen` will only trace `open()` system calls
- `-ofile` will log the output to a file called `file`

Now wait for the process to stall in state `D`. While the process is blocked you can inpect the file `strace.log`. Contents may look like

```
$ tail -f strace.log
[...]
open("...", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("...", O_RDONLY)
open("/path/to/suspect_file", O_RDONLY)
```

The last entry in the log - `/path/to/suspect_file` in the above example - is the file where `rsync` blocks in the uninterruptible sleep. You can now exclude that file from being rsynced or check why it causes the block (or try to copy it manually).

---

BTW: A programm that copies a lot of files will be in the uninterruptible sleep most of the time. This means that the programm is waiting most of the time for the underlying filesystem (which is very slow compared to cpu cycles).